# G-Sync monitor to laptop HDMI port

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport, g-sync

Recently I bought laptop thinkpad x1 carbon (4th gen) and I want to connect it to my monitor(acer XB240H). Laptop is with win 10 pro and Intel HD graphics 520.

The laptop supports only HDMI and monitor has only DP port so I bought another hdmi-dp cable. The problem is that when I connect it - laptop can not detect the monitor.
Even more weird for me is that when I try to use same cable to connect monitor and my desktop pc it doesn't work either, although DP-DP cable does work. 
I wonder if this is windows problem, g-sync problem(monitor supports g-sync, although I do not care about it for now and could disable it if possible and would help), cable problem or something entirely different?
So far I have tried reinstalling and updating display adapters but that didn't work either.

Comment: Is the HDMI-DP cable you have a passive or active cable? http://www.overclock.net/t/721931/active-vs-passive-displayport-adapters-the-truth

Comment: passive i guess...paid like 13 euros, doesn't say on the box

Comment: I'd suggest picking up an active DP-HDMI adapter and trying it out. It'll probably cost closer to $40 than $13, just make sure you can return it if it does not work for you :)